# What is the difference between datadir and innodb_data_home_dir in mysql?

Tags: mysql, configuration

What is the difference between the datadir and the innodb_data_home_dir ? mysql documentation for these configuration variables is too little.

Please explain what both of them are used for and how keeping them the same or different makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

This here explains it pretty well.
http://www.suntechzone.com/tutorial/stmysql/stmysql651.html

Basically, the innodb_data_home_dir is telling mysql where to create the InnoDB table space.  In versions including and prior to 3.23, you had to give the innodb handler a file path or it wouldn't start, and subsequently your mysqld wouldn't start either.  But now, that's behind us and MySQL will automatically do this for you if you don't explicitly set it.

I don't know if there is any real advantage of having them separate except for the fact that InnoDB uses transactional data and is doing more writing on your storage media.  So it might benefit you to have that on a different set of disks than your datadir if you need to have more speed dealing with innodb tables.

Comment: so what does the datadir store then ?

Comment: The datadir is the default place for the mysql data.  SO, if you leave innodb_data_home as default, it'll get stored here.  MyISAM table data will also be stored here.  Basically, it gives you more granular control over where your tablespace data is kept.  For example, by default on a bunch of linux distros, the datadir is /var/lib/mysql but you might move it if you've got a faster raid set up on /var/data or elsewhere.